# JQuery Datatable - Back button without clearing search condition and pagination in MVC razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I use JQuery datatable in my MVC razor views. I want to implement a Back button and clicking on that button it should be redirected to the page from where it had opened.

i.e., It should not clear the search condition and pagination on redirect.

**Suppose:**

I have a list of Employees. I have searched for department as IT whose result has 5 pages (10 records on each page). I have clicked on the 3rd page and then I clicked on Edit button of any one employee. On the Edit page if I again click on the Back button it should redirect me to the 3rd page with search condition as IT.

Comment: you need to store values of pages and search criteria in JS global variables. and while clicking `Back` button you just need to pass page value in `oTable.fnPageChange(3)` as follow ..

Comment: @mmushtaq Thanks. I will try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only use this option for datatable:  `stateSave: true`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myTable = $('#myDataTable').DataTable({
        ...
        stateSave: true
        });
});
```

[Read more...](https://datatables.net/reference/option/stateSave)

Answer (score 1):

you can get `page` info as follow:

```
$('#datatable').on('page.dt', function() {
    var info = table.page.info();
   var page = info.page;
});
```

I have created a JsFiddle for you.. This might be help..

> ***<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mmushtaq/qpLtLfaz/168/)</kbd>***